# How to execute a JQuery function when page loads and when it's called from another place

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to make a slideshow in jquery where images would start rotating as soon as the page loads, but when someone hovers over an image slideshow would pause and then continue when mouse leaves the image. I tried this:

```
function start_slideshow(){
    var images = $("#galerija img");
    var img_num = images.length;
    var counter=-1;

    var ciklus = window.setInterval(function () {
      if (counter == img_num) {
        counter = 0;
      }
      else{
        counter++;
      }

      $('#glavna_slika img').attr('src',$(images[counter]).attr('src'));
    }, 3000);
  }

$(document).ready(function(){

  start_slideshow;

  $("#galerija img").hover(function(){
    $('#glavna_slika img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    window.clearInterval(ciklus);
  }, start_slideshow);
});
```

But the function isn't called when the page is loaded (the callback function works though). If I don't encapsulate the code of start_slideshow() in a function I don't know how to resume the automatic image rotation and if I do keep it in a function I don't know how to have it execute on page load.

Comment: I can't edit the code since the change would alter the original question, but I discovered another mistake in the code. The Interval isn't cleared here since "ciklus" variable is out of scope. I put the hover event in the "start_slideshow()" function and made a callback function a separate function and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke methods with brackets. i.e. start_slideshow();
Otherwise you're just writing out variables, like "hello world"; or 42;

You can supply methods as variables too, but they will never get executed without the brackets!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `()` from `start_slideshow()`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Err. Apart from, it does answer the question, because he/she was asking why the function wasn't called...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the () of the function call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  start_slideshow();   //  <--- here

  $("#galerija img").hover(function(){
    $('#glavna_slika img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    window.clearInterval(ciklus);
  }, start_slideshow);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function "start_slideshow" is not being invoked on load.
    Use `start_slideshow();`